# dynamically populate and print 2D array in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, search, multidimensional-array

I am looping through a 2D array in order to find if the values from column 1 are already present on the sheet. If they are, I would like to paste the value from column 2 in the same column it was found. The code I have is below... I am not receiving any errors but there are not any values being printed.

The range I am pasting into needs to be dynamic and right now is based on the array titled "myArrayNoBlanks" (a dynamic array that populates the original values I am pulling for my data). Perhaps changing the range to something that would find the last column would do the trick?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
For h = 1 To 11

Set PartRange = Worksheets(12).UsedRange.Columns(col(h))
Set CostRange = Worksheets(12).UsedRange.Columns(Cost(h))

    For Each cell In PartRange.Cells
        If cell.Row > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve myParts(var)
        myParts(var) = cell.Value
        var = var + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In CostRange.Cells
        If cell.Row > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve myCost(varc)
        myCost(varc) = cell.Value
        varc = varc + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    myNewArray = Array(myParts, myCost)

    For w = LBound(myNewArray, 1) To UBound(myNewArray, 1)

        Dim cols As Integer
        Dim ans As Boolean
        Dim sch As Long
        sch = myNewArray(w)(2)
        Dim ch As Range
        Dim rngs As Range
        Set rngs = Range("B1")
        Set rngs = rngs.Resize(1, UBound(myArrayNoBlanks))
        For Each ch In rngs
            If ch = sch Then
                ans = True
                cols = ch.Column
                    If h = 1 Then
                    Dim Dest1 As Range
                    Set Dest1 = Worksheets(14).Cells(2, cols)
                    Dest1.Value = sch
                    End If
            End If
        Next ch
        If IsNull(ans) Then ans = False


    Next w
```

Comment: BTW; there is no need to loop to load the arrays: `myParts = PartRange.Value` and do the same for the cost.

Comment: Will that still allow me to dynamically fill those two arrays?

Comment: Yes without the loop